# In PHP, why does `print 08+"51";` give 51?

Tags: php, math, addition

In PHP, I haved tried this code `print 08+"51";`
but I don't know why it gives 51, while `print 07+"51";` give 58 ?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php: `$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)`

Comment: The upvote button states "this question shows research effort". No research effort is obvious yet it stands with 4 upvotes.

Comment: 08 doesn't exist in octal

Comment: How did you not get Fatal Error?

Comment: @DavidPartyka: Because 08 is converted to 0, and "51" is converted to 51, so it gives 0+51 = 51

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when an integer starts with a 0 you are using octal. 08 is not a valid octal number so it translates to zero. 0 + 51 (because "51" is converted to a integer thanks to type juggling) equals 51.

Comment: It should be "converted to an integer" not "converted to a string" -- it is already a string

Comment: OK. How simple it is ! Thanks

Comment: @johannes You are correct. I changed how I wanted to explain it halfway through and in the end got a bit of both. Fixed.